# Whats is the highest value for Date type in AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm casting TIMESTAMP column type into DATE on AWS Athena with parquet files. For some reasons 2049-12-10 00:00:00 throughs an error. Is there any max date limits for this type?

Answer (score 0):

Presto (which Athena is based on) uses 32-bit signed integer to represent a date. The value is interpreted as "epoch day" (number of days since 1970-01-01), so max date value is 5881580-07-11.